# React: How to use one variable in one component when it is imported to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'components/Card';
import { dateFilter } from 'helpers';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-chart-matrix';
import chroma from 'chroma-js';
import moment from 'moment';

const WeeklyTrafficCard = (props) => {
  const { start, end, data, store } = props;
  const capacity = store && store.capacity;
  var numberOfweeks = 0; //representing how many weeks back
  const dateArray = [];

  var today = moment();
  while (numberOfweeks < 10) {
    var from_date = today.startOf('week').format('MM/DD/YY');
    var to_date = today.endOf('week').format('MM/DD/YY');
    var range = from_date.concat(' ','-',' ',to_date);
    dateArray.push(range);
    today = today.subtract(7, 'days');
    numberOfweeks++;
    //console.log(dateArray);
  }
  const [each_daterange, setDateRange] = useState();
```

I have this Component called WeeklyTrafficCard and I want to use the variable, each_daterange, in another component, which imported WeeklyTrafficCard as below to send the get request, clearly I cannot use each_daterange directly right here, how I can work around it?

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { WeeklyTrafficCard } from './WeeklyTrafficCard';
import { AppContext } from 'contexts/App';
import { API_URL } from 'constants/index.js';
import { todayOpen, todayClose } from 'helpers';
import moment from 'moment';

const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = (props) => {
  const { API } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { store = {} } = props;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const open = todayOpen(store.hours, store.timezone);
  const close = todayClose(store.hours, store.timezone);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await API.get(`${API_URL}/api/aggregates`, {
        params: {
          each_daterange,
          every: '1h',
          hourStart: 13,
          hourStop: 4
        },
      });
```

Comment: I see people telling you to use a state management for this but not that it's not necessary if you need to pass up a variable to the parent once. However, it is needed if you need to share data between component that are not direct parent=>child to avoid passing data through multiple component

Answer (score 0):

Keep the value outside of the component, where both can access it. There are [other](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) [ways](https://redux.js.org/) to do this, but just as a simple example you could create a simple "store" to hold it and reference that store from each component that needs it:

```js
class Store {
  setDateRange (newDateRange) {
    this._dateRange = newDateRange;
  }

  get dateRange () {
    return this._dateRange;
  }
}

export default new Store(); // singleton; everyone gets the same instance
```

```js
import store from './Store';

const WeeklyTrafficCard = (props) => {
  // use current dateRange value
  const dateRange = store.dateRange;

  // set new dateRange
  store.setDateRange( newDateRange );

  // do other stuff
}
```

```js
import store from './Store';

const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = (props) => {
  // use current dateRange value
  const dateRange = store.dateRange;

  // set new dateRange
  store.setDateRange( newDateRange );

  // do other stuff  
}
```

If you want store updates to trigger component re-renders you'd need to add some [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) plumbing, like redux's connect, or some other mechanism for triggering updates:

```js
// pseudocode; make store an event emitter and return
// a component that re-renders on store events
store.connect = Component => {
  return props => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      store.addEventListener( ... )
      return () => store.removeEventListener( ... )
    })
  }
}
```

---

Or if the components share a common parent, you could [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent and pass the information to each component as props. If either component updates the value, the parent state change will trigger a re-render of both components with the new value:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = React.useState();

  return (
    <>
      <WeeklyTrafficCardContainer
        dateRange={dateRange}
        onDateRangeChange={newRange => setDateRange(newRange)}
      />
      <WeeklyTrafficCard
        dateRange={dateRange}
        onDateRangeChange={newRange => setDateRange(newRange)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your first method works. Definitely do not do this (the store method) _everytime_ you need to pass data up from a child. Will certainly bloat your application. Name the store WeeklyTraffic store or something to directly tie it to where it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `useEffect`(prop drilling) to pass your variable in your parent:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <Child setMyVar={setMyVar} />
      {myVar}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({setMyVar}) => {
  const myChildVar = "Hello world !"

  React.useEffect( () => setMyVar(myChildVar),[]);
  return <div> This is the child</div>
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the [repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-ptdlkc)

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding of the Problem**

You want to pass data up to the parent from the child.

**Manage `each_daterange` in the parent:**

Instead of creating your `useState` variable `each_daterange` in the child you can declare it in the parent and pass down it's setter function. For instance:

```js
const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = (props) => { 
 const [eachDateRange, setEachDateRange] = useState();

 return (
  <div>
   {/* your return */}
   <WeeklyTrafficCard setEachDateRange={setEachDateRange} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

If you need to display `eachDateRange` in the traffic card, or the traffic card needs to completely own that variable, you can create another state variable in the parent and pass a callback to the child (essentially what is above but now you have two different state variables).

The parent becomes

```js
const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = (props) => { 
 const [requestDateRange, setRequestDateRange] = useState();

 const updateRequestDateRange = (dateRange) => { 
  setRequestDateRange(dateRange)
 }

 return (
  <div>
   {/* your return */}
   <WeeklyTrafficCard updateDateRange={updateRequestDateRange} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Then in your `WeeklyTrafficCard` call `props.updateDateRange` and pass it the date range whenever `each_daterange` changes.

Comment: You can improve this by using the useCallback hook so that updateRequestDateRange is not created on every re render

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, of course you need a global state manager. My preferred is [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). In few word, react-redux allows you to have a state that is shared in all your components. Sharing `each_daterange` between `WeeklyTrafficCardContainer` and `WeeklyTrafficCard` will be very easy if you decide to use it.
[This](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) is the more appropriate guide to quick start with react-redux. have a nice coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase the objective here.

Objective: access each_daterange from WeeklyTrafficCard component in WeeklyTrafficCardContainer component.

Note: simply put, choose the following case based on your problem.

- choose using prop if the variable is to be accessed by only one component
- choose using context if the variable is to be accessed by more than one components

Solution Cases:

**Case A: using prop.**

**Case A.1. WeeklyTrafficCard is the parent of WeeklyTrafficCardContainer**

- each_datarange being passed from WeeklyTrafficCard component as prop to WeeklyTrafficCardContainer component
- working example for reference: [codesandbox - variable passed as prop](https://codesandbox.io/s/value-passed-as-prop-to-another-component-gj19n)

```js
// WeeklyTrafficCard.jsx file
const WeeklyTrafficCard = () => {
  const [each_daterange, setDateRange] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <WeeklyTrafficCardContainer eachDateRange={each_daterange} />
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
// WeeklyTrafficCardContainer.jsx file
const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = props => {
  const eachDateRange = props.eachDateRange;

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

**Case A.2. WeeklyTrafficCard & WeeklyTrafficCardContainer are children of a parent, say WeeklyTraffic component**

- each_datarange will be present in WeeklyTraffic component which is shared among WeeklyTrafficCard component & WeeklyTrafficCardContainer component

```js
// WeeklyTraffic.jsx file
const WeeklyTraffic = () => {
  const [each_daterange, setDateRange] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <WeeklyTrafficCard eachDateRange={each_daterange} />

      <WeeklyTrafficCardContainer eachDateRange={each_daterange} />
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
// WeeklyTrafficCard.jsx file
const WeeklyTrafficCard = props => {
  const eachDateRange = props.eachDateRange;

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
// WeeklyTrafficCardContainer.jsx file
const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = props => {
  const eachDateRange = props.eachDateRange;

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

**Case B: using context.**

- follow blog example found: [blog - react context](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-context)
- this is preferred way to implement if the variable/variables is/are shared or need to be accessed by more than 1 components